# Number statics VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program which will be able to add 10 random numbers in a list. After this you have the possibility to see what the lowest,highest, avarage and median numbers are.

```
Public Class number
    Private _numbers As List(Of Integer)

    Public Property numbers() As List(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return _numbers
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Integer))
            _numbers= value
        End Set
    End Property

     Public Function addnumber() As Integer
        Dim rnd As New Random

        For teller As Integer = 0 To 9
            _numbers(teller) &= rnd.Next(0, 1001)
        Next

        Return _numbers.Sort
    End Function
End Class
```

At the end of the code (`Return _numbers.Sort`) it says expression does not produce a value. 
Any tips to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code.

First, to answer your question: look at the [documentation of `List.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It *doesn’t* return a value. It sorts the list in-place.

Next, you cannot use `&=` with a list of integers in the following line:

```
_numbers(teller) &= rnd.Next(0, 1001)
```

If this code compiles without complaint, then you need to enable `Option Strict` in the project settings (and do it globally, for good measure). `&=` is a string concatenation operator.

Next, your code attempts to overwrite items in the list, but you never specified that the list should have 10 items. Hence, this will fail at runtime with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. You need to `Add` the items to the list — again, refer to the documentation.